# Set Large text in TexArea LWUIT

Tags: text, textarea, lwuit

I have static text of around 800 characters. I want to know a way to show it all in one place. I was trying to show it from TextArea LWUIT, but apparently it is giving me illegal arguement exception. Please help as I have wasted a lot of time on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got it to work :) Following is the workaround for it:

```
helpText = new TextArea(text);
    helpText.setRows(15);

    helpText.setColumns(30);
```

Trick is to add rows and columns separately and dont use setText(text).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the maxSize propierty from the `TextArea`? I mean if you try to put a value to the  maxSize...using `TextArea.setMaxSize(800)`

Comment: yes i did this too, but it did not work. It kept on giving the same Illegal argument exception. Could you tell me the use of rows and columns in the header of TextArea. What do they mean?

Comment: I think that rows and columns are for setting a determined size of the TextArea. If you want to auto adjustable TextArea, you should use setGrowByContent(true);

Comment: I tried everything but it dint work for...my solution was the only thing that worked :D

Answer (score 0):

try this.

textArea.setSingleLineTextarea(false);